# comparison of two sampled distributions

Tags: time-series, distributions, climate

I have two precipitation runoff time series (daily values of over 20 years): observational and model based. As shown in following figure [image: attached]I want to determine how much one distribution based on time series A is different from time series B?
Need advise on type of statistical test to help with it.

Comment: What are the axes in your figure?

Comment: x-axis: runoff (9-100) and y-axis: frequency (0-1)

Comment: Why do you use the distributions? Are you interested in similarity of the populations? Is each time instant exchangeable with others? If not, you should rather calculate e.g. mean square error between the two time series.

Comment: its a comparison of past and future climate so mainly want to see how similar/different both distributions are?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Kolmogorov-Snirnov test.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test?wprov=sfla1

Comment: KS test is applicable for daily or only annual values?